# Fork swap possible or not worth it? Fat bike tapered

Tags: fork, fatbike

I got a Fat Bike With a FAT Fork that is tapered. For summer riding, I swap out to a 29+ 2.2” Wheelset.   However, That Fat fork just feels like an anchor and I’d love to be able to swap it out too for a slimmer, lighter Surly Ogre or Krampus fork. IF POSSIBLE.  These Surly forks are a strait 1-1/8” tube.

1) Can I use some sort of tapered to strait adaptor?  And how complex for a non-mechanic/ tinker level novice?

2) Are there comparable tapered forks like the Surly ones mentioned I should consider instead?   I want something with a lot of mounting zits for bikepacking.

3) Other solutions besides buying a new bike?

This is my Fat Bike spec:
[image]

Comment: If you can possibly swing it, a second bike is a great option.   It avoids chopping between forks and having to reset bearings etc.

Comment: I have thought this over too.   Weighing different options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do to use a straight fork like a Surly is put a reducer crown race on it. The one for this would be FSA part number 160-5540.

[image]

Steel forks with tapered steerers aren't popular because things get so heavy. I don't know of any, although that doesn't mean there aren't any. There are some carbon ones like the Salsa Firestarter.